# Fill a CoreData entity from different viewControllers

Tags: ios, core-data, uiviewcontroller, entity, fill

I built a Core data model with different entities for my database, on my iPad app. I do want to access these attributes (and fill the dBase) from different viewControllers. For instance, there are UITextFields in viewController A, and another UITextField in viewController. I'd like the seized information to fill different attributes from my Core Data entity...

Is that possible? What is the best practice to do so?

My problems :

- I declare the objects with type "entity" in viewController A
- I fill different attributes of this entity with the seized text, also in viewController A
- I store the objects (same type as my entity) in a NSMutableArray in viewController A
- I use different methods to save and retrieve this NSMutableArray in viewController A

Any help or advice would be appreciated! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here comes the power of MVC. Make a class (model as of M of MVC) which is responsible for you data manipulation - fetching, updating, deleting, etc... Make this class either singleton or add a property in the AppDelegate and take in every `UIViewController` you need it. Collect all the data from the view controllers somewhere else - eg. some dictionary or something, then call a method of your data class that will insert the data, when ready... Good design always leads to less problems and difficulties with implementation and also makes further changes to the UI easy and fast...

Comment: Hey!

So, after creating my "graphic model" for the dbase, I indeed crated some classes, named after the entities, containing all the attributes as properties. What you mean is that I should use these classes in order to handle the data and record them in the dBase, then call these methods where I need, elsewhere in my project?

Comment: The classes you create are entities. I advice you to create another class that only uses these entities. For example, you have an entity Person (with attributes name, address, postcode, etc..). Create a class that has method: -(void)addPersonWithName:(NSString *)name address:(NSString *)address ..and so on. Add methods for manipulating all your database in this class and use only this class with your methods to insert/update/delete and so on. The general idea is your database manipulation to be independent of your UI

Comment: You may read some articles on designing using MVC and when you are comfortable with MVC design you may never face problems similar to the question you have asked...

Comment: Thanks a lot... i clearly see what you mean now! thanks for the help!